# AJAX failed status didn't work when submit form incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a form in an `HTML` static page, using the `https://formcarry.com/` website to work it and send without using PHP. I builded it with `AJAX` with a `spinner` and a `toggleclass` and `appendtext` to show the feedback when the submit was `successful`. I have an `alert()` when the submit fails, the problem is that the alert didn't work, never show it. You can see an live example [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/contacto.html).

The form can fail when:

1. User didn't write the mail.
2. User didn't write the input text message or name.User didn't write
   the input text message or name.
3. User send a few submits without waiting more than 15 seconds between
   them.

If that happens (the form fails), it only shows a infinite spinner, didn't show the alert.

HTML:

```
<form class="ajaxForm" action="https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
        <!-- use this to reply visitors and prevent spam via akismet -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="textarea" name="Mensaje" placeholder="Cuéntanos"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_gotcha">
    <!-- use this to prevent spam -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-contacto float-right">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.ajaxForm {
/* height: 297px; */
    width: 460px;
}
.form-control,
.form-control:active,
.form-control:hover,
.form-control:focus {
    border: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #c33e69;
    color: #fff;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
}
input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
input::-moz-placeholder,
textarea::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
}
input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
    /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) !important;
}
input.footer-input.footer-input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea.footer-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
}
input.footer-input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea.footer-input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
input.footer-input::-moz-placeholder,
textarea.footer-input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
input.footer-input:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea.footer-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
}
input.footer-input::-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea.footer-input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
}
input.footer-input::placeholder,
textarea.footer-input::placeholder {
    /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
    color: rgb(195, 62, 105, 0.40) !important;
}
.btn-contacto {
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px #c33e69 solid;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #c33e69;
    background: #fff;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
}
.spinner-border {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    color: #fbc00c;
}
/* Change the white to any color ;) */

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #c33e69 inset !important;
}
/* Change the white to any color ;) */

input.footer-input:-webkit-autofill,
input.footer-input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input.footer-input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input.footer-input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #c33e69 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #fff inset !important;
}
.ajaxForm {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.has-success {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e) {
        $('.spinner-border').css("display", "block");
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: href,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == "success") {
                    $(".ajaxForm").toggleClass("has-success");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".ajaxForm").html(response);
                        $(".ajaxForm").toggleClass("has-success").append("<div class='swal2-icon swal2-success swal2-animate-success-icon' style='display: flex;'><div class='swal2-success-circular-line-left' style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'></div><span class='swal2-success-line-tip'></span><span class='swal2-success-line-long'></span><div class='swal2-success-ring'></div> <div class='swal2-success-fix' style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'></div><div class='swal2-success-circular-line-right' style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'></div></div><p class='text-center'>¡Gracias! Contactaremos contigo lo antes posible.</p>");
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    alert("An error occured.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://formcarry.com/s/YN2IlAj4rfL' from origin 'http://residenciarucab.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
` your target action URL is not permit you to post using ajax.

Comment: You must use "error" callback.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
read success callback and error callback. plus for some reason it sends form 2 times in a row, for me at least

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur I was sending forms a few minutes ago and It worked. These message only show when u submit a few forms without waiting 15 sec between them.

Comment: If there will be an `error` from API it will never go inside the `success` callback of ajax. So you should handle the error in `error` callback as suggested by @Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use error callback to handle API failures. You can read about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: href,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response){
    //This function triggers only if the request succeeds
        if(response.status == "success"){

        }else{

        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
         //Function triggers when API call fails
    }       
});
```

Comment: It's basically the same code that I had but with: error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
         //Function triggers when API call fails
    } .The problem is when I insert it the AJAX desactivates and send like a normal form without AJAX, redirecting to me to the formspring submit success or submit failed page.

Comment: cmon, you missed a comma, just comma

Comment: comma, where? I don't know what u mean.

Comment: I had missed comma after success function.

Comment: @Ashish now work's fine. Now how I can manage the callback error to show when an input required isn't writed? When I solve that I will make your question as resolved ;)

Comment: you can handle scenarios based on response inside error callback just like your success callback and do stuffs, you did there.